# Click event box inside box in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have code:

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    box.forEach(function(element) {
        element.onclick = function() {
            alert(this.innerText);
        }
    });
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red">
        A
        <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click Box B, I just want to show "B" not "AB". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` which stops the click event from bubbling to parent element like the following:

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll("div");
box.forEach(function(element) {
    element.onclick = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert(this.innerText);
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red">
    A
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;">
        B
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.solution:** You could cancel all other events using `event.stopPropagation();` Have a look at the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

*event.stopPropagation-Description*: `Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.`

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll("div");
box.forEach(function(element) {
    element.onclick = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert(this.innerText);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red">
    A
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;">
        B
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. solution:** You could of course also use the method to separate the two div elements like this:

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll("div");
box.forEach(function(element) {
  element.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red">
  A
</div>


<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;">
  B
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your need.

```js
function a(div) {
alert(div.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: red">A
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;" onclick="a(this);">B</div>
</div>
```